# Counting total number of productivity to a master spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have several spreadsheets that lists the total number of users that are contacted and their respective dates on which they are contacted. I want to create a master spreadsheet that auto counts the total productivity (number of users contacted) every 7 and every month. If it's possible that is.

Comment: This is possible, and potentially quite simple. Unfortunately the question is impossible to answer in any detail. Please check the guidelines on how to ask questions and make it more specific plus show what you've tried.

Comment: Sorry guys for not adding more detail. Here's one of the spreadsheet I'm using. I'm counting their productivity every 7 days (Friday - Thursday) and every month. I just want to have it somewhat automated.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zRNkY3jeN3_uIgckmxKue280uUeTacVF5U1iZWwoPmA/edit?usp=sharing